# Paypal Preapproval Start Date timezone?

Tags: php, timezone, paypal

I'm setting up an application using Paypal Adaptive Payments.

I'm currently implementing the call to the Preapproval, and the specification says the StartDate can not be before today.

With that in mind... under which timezone are they validating this against?

The API SDK has this in the example:

```
$currDate = getdate();
$startDate = $currDate['year'].'-'.$currDate['mon'].'-'.$currDate['mday'];
$startDate = strtotime($startDate);
$startDate = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0,0,0,date('m',$startDate),date('d',$startDate),date('Y',$startDate)));
$endDate = add_date($startDate, 1);
```

However that date can be different based on the timezone of the server sending the request.

Anyone have any ideas on how to ensure no issues will occur?

Edit w/ Bounty:

As of December 15th, we have now run into this as an error. We are using UTC time, and once it turns a new day in UTC, payments start getting failures.

I am using the above code in the following place:

```
$preapprovalRequest->startingDate = $startDate;
$preapprovalRequest->endingDate = $endDate;
```

What do I need to make this work?

Edit 2:

Yes timezone is setup as UTC, we did this intentionally so that all time information in our database is stored without timezone.

Essentially I'm trying to figure out how to specify that the date I'm sending to Paypal is in UTC, not whatever timezone they happen to be in.

Edit 3:

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APPreapproval

There is the API, and it says the following

> The startingDate and endingDate can be in eiter Zulu or GMT offset
>   formats. as in the following respective examples: 
>   2010-09-10Z 
>   2010-09-10T17:24:03.874-07:00

Essentially I need the above code, to output something like that specifying I'm using UTC...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP time functions are based on system time (http://us.php.net/manual/en/intro.datetime.php). Are you sure your system is setup to use UTC time? You can check with the following:

```
mpurcell@service1 ~/projects/config $ -> date
Thu Dec 15 23:29:09 UTC 2011
```

Notice the UTC in the response. If your system is setup to some other timezone, then that may be your problem, if you need to set your timezone to UTC, try:

```
$ rm -f /etc/localtime
$ ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC /etc/localtime
```

Also be sure that your system time is corrected using Network Time Protocol:

```
$ ntpdate -b pool.ntp.org
```

-- Edit --

Based on your edits, looks like they are expecting the time in either Zulu (append Z) or GMT with offset (more complex), try this:

```
$preapprovalRequest->startingDate = $startDate . 'Z';
$preapprovalRequest->endingDate = $endDate . 'Z';
```

Comment: Yes our system is setup to use UTC time to assist in allowing all users proper display of time.

Comment: @AequitarumCustos: Did you check the API docs to see if there is a `$preapprovalRequest->timezone` call?

Comment: Added API link and info on timezone from the API doc. I don't understand how to use what they put there.

Answer (score 7):

The [api documentation](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APPreapproval) says it uses GMT or Zulu time over the wire, and expects it to have a final 'Z' to indicate this (consistent with ISO 8601).

> Additional Notes About the PreApproval API Operation
>
> 1. Preapproval constraints are additive; thus, for example, if you specify a preapproval that allows payments only on Fridays and on the 13th day of the month, the preapproval would be valid only on Friday the 13th of months within the specified time period.
> 2. The startingDate and endingDate can be in eiter Zulu or GMT offset formats. as in the following respective examples:
>
> `2010-09-10Z` **[NOTE: THIS IS ZULU]**
>
> `2010-09-10T17:24:03.874-07:00`  **[NOTE: THIS IS GMT OFFSET]**

The safest thing to use is probably this:

```
$startingDate = gmdate('Y-m-d\Z', $startingDateTimestamp);
```

However, you *must make absolutely sure* that your own server's time zone (and time!) is set correctly.  **You may also need to set timezone separately in your PHP application** using [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).

**Finally,** there's another wrinkle--I do not know what SDK you are using. Possibly it tries to be clever and changes the date you pass in to something else. In that case you need to find out what date translation it does and what date it expects. (E.g., perhaps it expects a date in the system-local time, and it changes it to a UTC time.)  Assuming it doesn't alter what you supply, however, you should be able to use the code above.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information, used the other solution so marked it as accepted solution, but this will probably be best answer for users who find this question so giving you the bounty!

Comment: @AequitarumCustos: What the heck? Just mark this the solution then. Doesn't make sense to award bounty to one and solution to other.